# ffmpeg to convert from flac to wav

Tags: ffmpeg, wav, wave, flac

I need to convert a flac file to a wav file without changing sample rate and bit depth. As far as I know changing these properties may distort the audio, so how do i specify them not to be changed?

Also, is there any way to prevent metadata to be written to the output file?

Comment: ffmpeg -i <input> output.wav may work for you

Answer (score 44):

As rogerdpack commented, the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.flac output.wav
```

should do exactly what you want.

Addressing your concerns about keeping the resulting audio intact, FLAC is a lossless format and decoding it to raw PCM stored in a WAV file will keep perfect fidelity. The only thing you might have to be concerned about is if your FLAC file is a higher than normal bit depth like 24, 32 or 64 bits per sample, or has a crazy multichannel configuration. I haven't kept up on whether FFmpeg supports all those combinations. However, most FLAC files are just 16-bit, 44.1 kHz audio files, so this shouldn't be an issue.

About scrubbing metadata, check this [Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'have already figured out that bit depth converts to 16bit from higher, so I need to set it manually.

Comment: Any idea what version of PCM is ffmpeg using? (i.e. `pcm_s16le`, `pcm_f64le`)

Comment: Depends on what format you ask it to use; if you don't, it uses whatever is appropriate based on the input and output.

Answer (score 9):

```
sox infile.flac outfile.wav
```

should do exactly that, without copying metadata.

I used it to convert back a sound that grip converted from wav to flac and got exactly the same file as the original wav.