# Out of ffmpeg and flac which should be used to convert wav files to flac? Why?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, wav, flac

Considering:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4045/convert-wav-files-to-flac
and
[ffmpeg to convert from flac to wav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333678/ffmpeg-to-convert-from-flac-to-wav)

Out of `ffmpeg` and `flac` which should be used to convert `wav` files to `flac`? WHY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Both will make the same decoded output

1. Make FLAC from WAV:

   ```
   $ ffmpeg -i input.wav ffmpeg.flac
   $ flac -o flac.flac input.wav
   ```
2. Compare [MD5 hashes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#md5-1) of each decoded file:

   - The input file:

     ```
     $ ffmpeg -v 1 -i input.wav -f md5 -
       MD5=1a567b5d97e62a6656283d24850b707f
     ```
   - `ffmpeg` output:

     ```
     $ ffmpeg -v 1 -i ffmpeg.flac -f md5 -
       MD5=1a567b5d97e62a6656283d24850b707f
     ```
   - `flac` output:

     ```
     $ ffmpeg -v 1 -i flac.flac -f md5 -
       MD5=1a567b5d97e62a6656283d24850b707f
     ```

This shows that both `ffmpeg` and `flac` make the exact same output when decoded, **and** the decoded output of the FLAC files are exactly the same as the decoded WAV file.

#### Differences

- `flac` was slightly faster in my single, lazyass test, but not significantly.
- `ffmpeg` can decode a huge variety of formats (not that you should be making FLAC files from lossy inputs).
- `ffmpeg` will always attempt to copy any existing metadata (but see `--keep-foreign-metadata` for `flac`).

#### Summary

Both are great tools, so use whatever you prefer.

Comment: Note that ffmpeg is not capable of copying .wav RIFF chunk metadata over to .flac. flac can with the flag `flac sample.wav --keep-foreign-metadata`. In this situation flac is a better tool